# Realtime database write not working with firebase serve

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write to my realtime database and have the following rules:

```
{
 "rules": {
    ".read" : true,  
    "users" : {
      ".write" : "auth != null"
    }
 }
}
```

It's working fine when I'm using `127.0.0.1:8887`, but when I host my website using, firebase server, functions, and hosting, it asks me to go to `localhost:5000` and the database write doesn't work.

Any suggestions as to why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a hard time what you're doing, and what the problem is. I gave an answer below explaining the Firebase CLI and the Realtime Database emulator. If that doesn't help you solve the problem, please describe exactly (but minimally) what you're doing, noting that code (or commands executed) by far trump written words on what you're doing/trying. Also have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which contains more useful hints when asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase CLI that you run with `firebase serve` only serves Firebase Hosting files, and HTTPS Cloud Functions for Firebase. It does not serve the Firebase Realtime Database locally.

There **is** a local emulator for testing security rules for the Realtime Database, but this is not integrated into the Firebase CLI in any way. For more information, see the [documentation on the Firebase Realtime Database emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/test-rules-emulator).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for letting me know.